# Comparing new password and confirm new password using [Compare("",..)] doesnot work while using data annotations in MVC3, Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, compare, client-side-validation, data-annotations

I have three PasswordFor, oldpassword, newpassword and confirmnewpassword inside @using (Ajax.BeginForm()){---}, and i need these values bounded with a model and need the values of newpassword and confirmnewpassword validated in client side using data annotations. I have used [Compare("newpassword",errormessage="error message---"(] to compare values of newpassword and confirmnewpassword.
When I use only two PasswordFor for newpassword and confirmnewpassword, [Compare("newpassword"),..] works perfectly but when Password for oldpassword is also taken inside the Ajax.BeginForm, the Compare validation doesnot work. I need all these three values to be passed through model to my Controller and I am not able to use these three boxes in a same form which would compare newpassword and confirmnewpassword.
If oldpassword is taken outside the BeginForm() the compare works but the value of oldpassword is not validated using data annotations and its value is not being passed through the model to the controller.
All I need is to get this [Compare()] work while I have all these three PasswordFor within my Ajax.BeginForm and it's not submitted until all my validations have been validated in client-side.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

My view:

```
@model eremit.Models.CustomerAll
```

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("verifycustomer", "CustomerLogin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "messagediv" }))
                {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


                        <h3>Old password</h3>@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Login.oldpassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login.oldpassword)

                     <h3>New password</h3>@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Login.newpassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login.newpassword)

                        <h3>

                            Re-enter New password</h3>@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Login.confirmnewpassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login.confirmnewpassword)


                        <div id="messagediv">
                        </div>

                            <input type="submit" id="btnchangepassword" value="Change Password" />
```

My Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace eremit.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter old password")]
    public string oldpassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter new password")]
    [Display(Name = "newpassword")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z<>$@#!%&_0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Password")]
    public string newpassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Re-enter your new password")]
    [Compare("newpassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password     do not match.")]
    public string confirmnewpassword { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since MVC 3 is introduced,the Microsoft libraries such as **MicrosoftAjax.js**, **MicrosoftMvcAjax.js** and **MicrosoftMvcValidation.js** are obsolete.

These libraries are replaced by **jquery.validate.min.js**, **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js** as part of MVC3.Just comment the Microsoft helpers and try.

```
MicrosoftAjax.js
MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js
```